# How to solve this modular equation?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm quite good solving modular equations, but there are some equations that I have no idea how solve it, this for example: $19^n\equiv19 \mod{79256734939805710486}$ for $n>1$. The number on the right side (the modulus) is divisible by $19$. I can solve this equation easily if the number on the right side is not divisible by $19$. Is there a simple way solving this equation, and what is the value of n for this case ?

Comment: This came up in the past few days on the Mathematica SE forum but I cannot locate the right link. Anyway, divide  19^n-19-k*mod by 19, that takes it to computing `MultiplicativeOrder[19, 79256734939805710486/19]` (I am posting a Mathematica-specific approach because that's where this question was raised; it was moved to math.SE while I was typing this.)

Comment: Here is the [thread I was looking for](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141556/modular-equation-problem/141561#141561).

Answer (score 2):

As long as the modulus is not a multiple of $19^2$ you can just divide everything by $19$ and solve $19^{n-1}=1 \pmod {4171407102095037394}$ as the multiples of $19$ form a subring of the ring $\Bbb Z_{79256734939805710486}$.  If the modulus were a multiple of $19^2$ there would be no solution as every power of $19$ above the first would have two factors of $19$.